# Do i need to make all object instantiation via producer in CDI

Tags: java, cdi, weld-se

I just start a CDI project. In this project a Beans2 is injected inside a Beans1.
But the Beans2 has a method that create a file. This method instantiates the File Object like this :

```
new File('myPathFile');
```

Because this instantiation is not managed by the CDI container, Bean2 is not injected into Beans1. I try to make a producer to inject a File into the Beans2  but do i need to do the same thing for all java base class that i will use?

Is there another solution to simply use class that do not need to be inject?

Bean1 :

```
@Dependant
public class Bean1 implements Serializable {
    private @Inject @Bean2Producer Bean2 bean2;

    public void someMethod() {
        bean2.foo();
    }
}
```

Bean2 :

```
@Dependant
public class Bean2 extends AbstractClass implements Serializable {

    private @Inject @PathDir String pathDir;


    public Bean2(String param1, boolean param2) {
         super(param1, param2);
    }

    public void foo() {
        File file = new File(pathDir);
    }
}
```

pathDir Producer :

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ProjectProducer implements Serializable {
    @Produces
    @PathDir
    public String getPathDir() {
        try {
             return PropsUtils.geetProperties().getProperty(PATH_DIR);
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

PathDir annotation :

```
@Qualifier
@Target({FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, CONSTRUCTOR, TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface PathDir {}
```

In this example, PathDir is not Inject if new File is invoke in foo() method.

Comment: No, you don't need to make everything injectable. I recommend reading some documentation and tutorials so you actually understand what you're doing when you're using dependency injection, and most of all **why**.

Comment: I read the Weld Documentation and tutorials, but i don't understand why injection fails when everything is not injectable.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, it's impossible to say why things aren't working.

Comment: Sorry after some test, it appear pathDir, is never Inject. Do you know why? It is correctly inject in another bean

Comment: You're still not showing where the value of `pathDir` would be produced. Do you really understand how CDI works?

Comment: After some test, it appear that CDI don't want to inject into Managed beans intantciate via Producer. I don't know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why Bean2 is not injected into Bean1 is that there is **no suitable constructor in Bean2** so that CDI can automatically create an instance of it. Beans need to have a constructor with no parameters or a constructor with all parameters injected, see more in the **[Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjfzi.html)**

This is simple the *limitation* of CDI. If you want to pass arguments to your bean, you need to supply a setter method(s) to pass arguments after bean2 is injected. Or, in case you need to have some values during object creation (because the abstract parent requires them), you need to inject all constructor arguments, like this (`@Param1` and `@param2` are qualifiers):

```
public Bean2(@Inject @Param1 String param1, @Inject @Param2 boolean param2) {
     super(param1, param2);
}
```

**Alternatively**, you do not need to turn every object into a CDI bean, especially if you have requirements on constructor parameters. You may inject all dependencies manually after the bean is created. It means you do use `@Inject` in Bean2, but provide a setter method, inject into bean1 and set the value in postconstruct method of bean1, example follows:

Bean1 :

```
@Dependant
public class Bean1 implements Serializable {

    private @Inject @PathDir String pathDir; // inject pathDir here instead of in Bean2

    private Bean2 bean2; // without inject, created in init()

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        bean2 = new Bean2("param1", "param2");
        bean2.setPathDir(pathDir);  // set injected value manually
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        bean2.foo(); // here bean2.pathDir should be already initialized via setPathDir in init() method above
    }
}
```

Bean2 :

```
@Dependant
public class Bean2 extends AbstractClass implements Serializable {

    private String pathDir; 

    public Bean2(String param1, boolean param2) {
         super(param1, param2);
    }

    public void setPathDir(String pathDir) {
        this.pathDir = pathDir;
    }

    public void foo() {
        File file = new File(pathDir);
    }
}
```

Or even better, merge setPathDir and Bean2 constructor - it will be clear that pathDir is a required dependency for Bean2.